# How to avoid continuous alert on WebView Page Loading Finished?Android

Tags: javascript, android, webview, android-alertdialog

I have a Webview In that I am giving Some Instructions Page on webview page loading finished

This is my sample code

```
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

if (!getSharedPreferences("MainA_SP", MODE_PRIVATE)
        .getBoolean("checkbox", false)) {

    AlertDialog.Builder adb=new AlertDialog.Builder(MainA.this);
    LayoutInflater adbInflater = LayoutInflater.from(MainA.this);
    View eulaLayout = adbInflater.inflate(R.layout.instpopup, null);
    chkbx = (CheckBox)eulaLayout.findViewById(R.id.skip);
    adb.setView(eulaLayout);
    adb.setTitle("Welcome To Sample Page");
    adb.setMessage(Html.fromHtml("App Instructions ....."));
    adb.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            String checkBoxResult = "NOT checked";
            if (chkbx.isChecked())  checkBoxResult = "checked";
            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(MainA_SP, 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putString("skipMessage", checkBoxResult);
            // Commit the edits!
            editor.commit();
            return;
        } });

    adb.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            String checkBoxResult = "NOT checked";
            if (chkbx.isChecked())  checkBoxResult = "checked";
            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(MainA_SP, 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putString("skipMessage", checkBoxResult);
            // Commit the edits!
            editor.commit();
            return;
        } });
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(MainA_SP, 0);
    String skipMessage = settings.getString("skipMessage", "NOT checked");
    if (!skipMessage.equalsIgnoreCase("checked") ) adb.show();
}

try{
    if (progressBar.isShowing()) {
        progressBar.dismiss();
      .
      .
      .
      .

    }
}catch(Exception exception){
    exception.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

So Here Its working fine with Checkbox and sharedprefs

But the Problem Is that I have Given this alert in on page loading finished
So I am getting Alert multiple Times for a single url single page

I need to click the alert Every time I opens the App ... If I tick the Checkbox its not showing But For first run Alert is Showing Multiple Times

**Update**

I want to Show Alert on Page finished loading successfully

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show alert at once after finished so you can use boolean value to check whether it is visible or not like below example.

```
 private boolean alertVisiblity = false;

onPageFinished(){

//show your alert here
if(!alertVisiblity){
 alertVisiblity = true;
new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setTitle("Alert")
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        dialogInterface.dismiss();
                        alertVisiblity = false; //or if you want to show it once never make it false or you can make it false before next call
                    }
                }).show();


}
```

Comment: Thanks user@SwapnilNandapur... My Question is that When Web Page Loading finished Alert is showing continuously for first time(If I Tick the check box its will not show) I want to show Alert on page successful load